# Plotly - name 'iplot' is not defined

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

been playing around with plotly for Python, but constantly running into the same error message stated above. I installed plotly on Anaconda, getting the error message both on Jupyter and Spyder respectively:

```
#data manipulation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#loading csv
df = df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\hendev\Desktop\FIFA18 - Ultimate Team players.csv')

import plotly.graph_objs as go

# prepare data
x2017 = df.overall[df.added_date == 2017]
x2018 = df.overall[df.added_date == 2018]

trace1 = go.Histogram(
    x=x2017,
    opacity=0.75,
    name = "2017",
    marker=dict(color='rgba(171, 50, 96, 0.6)'))
trace2 = go.Histogram(
    x=x2018,
    opacity=0.75,
    name = "2018",
    marker=dict(color='rgba(12, 50, 196, 0.6)'))

data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = go.Layout(barmode='overlay',
                   title=' Rating added in 2017 and 2018',
                   xaxis=dict(title='students-staff ratio'),
                   yaxis=dict( title='Count'),
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** `$ from plotly.plotly import iplot` will work only till plotly `v3.10.0` The `plotly.plotly` module has been [deprecated](https://plot.ly/python/v4-migration/) in plotly `v4.0`. Check your version first:

```
$ python3 -c 'import plotly; print(plotly.__version__)' # for Python 3
$ python -c 'import plotly; print(plotly.__version__)' # for Python 2
```

`v4.0` onwards, the functionality has been split into two modes: **online** and **offline**.

**Online**

If you wish to have the figures rendered online, you will now need to import [chart-studio](https://plot.ly/python/chart-studio/) and use

`from chart_studio.plotly import plot, iplot`

**Offline**

If you want to render the images locally, you have multiple options:

```
from plotly.offline import iplot
# your code
iplot(fig)
```

or

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
fig = make_subplots(# your args)
# your code
fig.show()
```

or

```
import plotly.io as pio
# your code
pio.show(fig)
```

or

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(# your args)
# your code
fig.show()
```

You can read up more on the renderers [here](https://plot.ly/python/renderers/).

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to import it

```
from plotly.plotly import iplot
```

Comment: well then I get: cannot import name 'iplot' from 'plotly' ... should I reinstall maybe?

Comment: How are you calling it @calicationoflife? It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `iplot` with `py`:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
py.iplot(fig)
```

Just in case, if you want to plot in offline mode and save plot as `file.hmtl`:

```
import plotly.offline as py
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
py.iplot(fig, filename="file.html")
```

Do not be afraid of looking through in [documentation](https://plot.ly/python/): here you can find nice and understandable examples how to use `plotly` properly. For example, [here](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/#basic-bar-chart) you can see how to plot simple bar chart, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For Jupyter Notebook and Kaggle Notebooks, this helped me.

```
from plotly.offline import iplot
```