# iplot is unrecognized in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, plotly-python

I'm trying to follow along with the following YouTube tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D35m2CdMhVs

I set up the environment through Anaconda and am using Jupyter to code. I imported `pandas` and `plotly` for the code and yet the `iplot` function is not recognized.

The `import` statements in the code look like this:

```
import plotly
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import pandas as pd
```

This is the specific error message I'm getting:

> NameError: name 'iplot' is not defined

[image]

Comment: Instead of copying and pasting the errors that you encountered, please put a code segment that other viewers can use to replicate your work. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial is from 2018 and the author specifies the versions of some of the dependencies at the beginning of the tutorial. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57768002/1559401) answer, there has been a change in `plotly` between v3 and v4. According to [the official web site](https://plotly.com) 4.0 came in 2019.

Please check for compatibility between what is in the tutorial and what the version of the API you're using offers. Also quite often people mix Python 2.x with 3.x (especially if they polute the environment set by Anaconda and similar with direct calls to `pip`/`pip3`).

Comment: It's amazing how short the half-life of technology is! I appreciate the help.